# How to get a special text such as an italic style text or a bold style text when using scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am going to code a spider that get such a data structure as the form " {name: xxx,description: yyy} ".

My target web site is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple`

like below:
[image]

I tried my best to write my parse function(the xpath is copied from chrome):

```
    def parse(self, response):
        context = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[6]/text()')
        for c in context:
            print(c)
            print(c.extract())
        pass
```

and the output was:

```
<Selector xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[6]/text()' data='The word '>
The word
<Selector xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[6]/text()' data=', formerly spelled '>
, formerly spelled
 in
<Selector xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[6]/text()' data=', is derived 
from the '>
, is derived from the
....
```

Obviously the way can't get texts of special texts that are italic style or Hyperlinks, because
*apple* and **Old English** are disappeared.

How can I get the special text from a paragraph so that I can get the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer:

```
context = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[6]').xpath("string(.)")
```

and then call `get` function of context then I get what I need.